# Initialize server side multi-column sorting in Laravel Inertia Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am trying to create server side sorting, in Laravel Inertia Vue. It will work as multi-column sorting , currently I am unable to imply it in the project. It was a matter of minutes, when was using Livewire stack. But, incase of Inertia Vue, unable to re-create it. Please help me someone! Waiting for the revert.

This is what I have done so far,
This is what I have done so far,

Route

```
Route::put('/users/{column}', [UserController::class, 'sortBy'])->name('users.set-field');
```

Controller

```
class UserController extends Controller 
{
    public $sorts = [];

    public function index(Request $request) {
        $rowsQuery = User::query()->select('id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at')
                                  ->withRole();

        $rows = $this->applySorting($rowsQuery);

        return Inertia::render('Backend/Management/AudienceManagement/Users/Index', [
            'usersData' => $query,
            'sortingData' => $this->sorts
        ]);
    }

    public function sortBy($column) {
        if (! isset($this->sorts[$column])) return $this->sorts[$column] = 'asc';
        if ($this->sorts[$column] === 'asc') return $this->sorts[$column] = 'desc';
        unset($this->sorts[$column]);
    }

    public function applySorting($query) {
        foreach($this->sorts as $column => $direction) {
            $query->orderBy($column, $direction);
        }
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Component

```
<template>
    <!-- Data Table -->
    <data-table-base>
        <template #head>
            <data-table-heading class="pr-0">ID</data-table-heading>
            <data-table-heading sortable :direction="sorts['name'] ?? null" @click="sortBy('name')">Name</data-table-heading>
            <data-table-heading>Email</data-table-heading>
            <data-table-heading>Role</data-table-heading>
            <data-table-heading sortable :direction="sorts['created_at'] ?? null" @click="sortBy('created_at')">Date</data-table-heading>
        </template>
    </data-table-base>
</template>

<script>
    import DataTableBase from '@/Components/Custom/Table/Base'
    import DataTableHeading from '@/Components/Custom/Table/Heading'
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        components: {
            DataTableBase,
            DataTableHeading
        },

        props: {
            usersData: {
                type: Object
            },
            sortingData: {
                type: Array
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {
                sorts: this.sortingData
            }
        },

        methods: {
            sortBy(column) {
                axios.put(this.route('users.set-field', {
                    column: column
                })).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is the above approach correct? Am I following in the right direction? If yes, how should I go ahead with it. Please help someone.

Comment: Hello, here in StackOverflow, we avoid giving answers that are based on opinion (hence answers like "this is best practice" is unacceptable unless it's a standard by the framework). if you need a review of your code and perhaps suggestions on improving it, posting on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). if however, your code isn't working, it would help to show any errors or tell us what you're expecting to get and what you're getting instead so that we can diagnose the issue more precisely. (is it a Laravel issue or a Vue issue?)

Comment: @WiGeeky Hey, thanks for the revert, okay, I see, I'll surely keep that in mind. And Its'll set in the Laravel controller, I just have to set up the Vue component accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

recently I faced the same issue, if u are still looking for a solution here u go.

If u are using pagination, u don't need to create an additional API, you can use the GET u are using to show the datas.

In your component is better using Inertia, something like this wuold work:

```
setOrderBy(orderBy) {
            this.currentContactSortColumn = orderBy
            this.$inertia.get(route('show'), {
                'sort': orderBy,
                //'direction': 'asc'
            }, {
                preserveState: true
            })

        },
```

Then in the controller, u have to check for the sort if is empty set a default value

```
(empty($request->sort)) ? $request->sort = 'default_value' : '';
```

And last after using paginate

```
$contacts->appends(['sort' => $request->sort]);
```

:)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will surely give that a try :)